# How to decode json string stored in variable in php

Tags: php, json

i have a response encoded in JSON. Stored in a variable and trying to decode. But it not displaying any thing.
code is here

```
echo $response; //prints response like
```

({ "OrderStatus" : "REJECT", "OrderID" : "","PONumber" :"", "Reject Reason" : "INVALID_FLD_VALUE You have entered an Invalid Field Value 41111 for the following field: ccnumber", "AUTHCODE" : "", "ShippingCost" : "", "HandlingCost" : ""});

```
//Trimming braces etc
$routes = ltrim($response, '('); //left trim
$routes_comp= rtrim($routes, ');'); //right trim
echo "<br/>"; 
  echo $routes_comp;

  //decoding here 
   $jsoni=json_decode($routes_comp);
   $var= $jsoni->OrderStatus;
    print_r($var);

      exit;
```

i want order status value but its not displaying any thing.what is the actual way?.

Comment: What do you get when `print_r($jsoni);`?

Answer (score 1):

use json_decode($routes_comp, true); -- Wrong

**EDIT**
Tested your code creating response variable as you said it was;

```
$response = '({ "OrderStatus" : "REJECT", "OrderID" : "","PONumber" :"", "Reject Reason" : "INVALID_FLD_VALUE You have entered an Invalid Field Value 41111 for the following field: ccnumber", "AUTHCODE" : "", "ShippingCost" : "", "HandlingCost" : ""});';

$routes = ltrim($response, '('); //left trim
$routes_comp= rtrim($routes, ');'); //right trim
echo "<br/>"; 
  echo $routes_comp;

  //decoding here 
   $jsoni=json_decode($routes_comp);
   $var= $jsoni->OrderStatus;
    print_r($var);

      exit;
```

Got This

```
<br/>{ "OrderStatus" : "REJECT", "OrderID" : "","PONumber" :"", "Reject Reason" : "INVALID_FLD_VALUE You have entered an Invalid Field Value 41111 for the following field: ccnumber", "AUTHCODE" : "", "ShippingCost" : "", "HandlingCost" : ""}REJECT
```

So I think $response may be coprrupted somehow. Could you put var_dump before trimming and test again?

Comment: json_decode second arg defaults to false, what means that you get an array, not an object. The json is valid, by the way, I tested.

Comment: are you sure? default is object.

Comment: thanks i've done with this
$routes_comp=preg_replace('/\s+/', '',$routes_comp); 
$json=json_decode(stripslashes($routes_comp));
$os=$json->OrderStatus;

Comment: Indeed, I just saw it, whitespaces may cause problems, weird that I tested the code with whitespaces and it worked, actually

Answer (score 1):

Done with this tech.
actually the error was white spaces between json string words.

```
     $routes_comp=preg_replace('/\s+/', '',$routes_comp);
     $json=json_decode(stripslashes($routes_comp));
     $os=$json->OrderStatus;
```